# How to traverse through cells from up, down arrows added in toolbar of numpad in UITableView?

Tags: toolbar, custom-cell, numpad

```
 numberToolbar.items=[
            UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named: "icKeyboardArrowUp"), style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.traverseUp)),
            UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named: "icKeyboardArrowDown") , style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.traverseDown)),
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.donePressed))
        ]

        numberToolbar.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: Please detail what you want with desired output

Comment: I want to change cell border color from gray to black when textfield inside the cell is pressed. Once the keyboard comes up, added buttons i.e., icKeyboardArrowUp and icKeyboardArrowDown can be used to change focus of the cell up and down depending on buttons pressed.